# Literal out of range warning when iterating over all values of u8

Tags: rust

The range in a `for`-loop, as I understand, is lower-limit inclusive and upper-limit exclusive. This is introducing an issue in the following code:

```
fn main() {
    let a: u8 = 4;

    for num in 0..256 {
        if num == a {
            println!("match found");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to loop 256 times from 0 to 255, and this fits into the range of data supported by `u8`. But since the range is upper limit exclusive, I have to give 256 as the limit to process 255.  Due to this, the compiler gives the following warning.

```
warning: literal out of range for u8
 --> src/main.rs:4:19
  |
4 |     for num in 0..256 {
  |                   ^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(overflowing_literals)] on by default
```

When I execute this, the program skips the `for` loop.

In my opinion, the compiler has to ignore 256 in the range and accept the range as `u8` range.  Is it correct?  Is there any other way to give the range?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As alex already said, it's probably the best to iterate using bigger integer types (like `u32`) and cast it when comparing to the `u8` you're searching for:

```
let a: u8 = 4;

for num in 0..256 {
    if (num as u8) == a {
        println!("match found");
        break;
    }
}
```

In this special case you can use [a half-open range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html), too:

```
let a: u8 = 4;

for num in 0.. {
    if num == a {
        println!("match found");
        break;
    }
}
```

> Also when I execute this, the program skips the for loop.

The binary representation of 256 is `1_0000_0000`. `u8` only saves the 8 rightmost bits, so just `0`s. Thus `0..256u8` is equivalent to `0..0`, which of course is an empty range.

Comment: The half-open range is what I need. But without the break, it creates an infinite loop, so one needs to be careful. The half-open range is missing in Rust documentation?

Comment: @Steve: It is called [`RangeFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFrom.html). There's also `RangeTo` and `RangeFull`.

Comment: The idea of using a half-open range is quite interesting, I wonder if it obviates part of the need for an inclusive range.

Comment: Still I think there should be a way in the language to express the full u8 range without the use of typecast.

Comment: @Steve I think many agree. But this is a huge debate in the community already, usually about syntax. Better not start a new discussion here in the comments :P

Answer (score 6):

You can combine iterators to create full `u8` range:

```
use std::iter::once;
for i in (0..255).chain(once(255)){
    //...
}
```

In nightly Rust you can use [inclusive range](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/enum.RangeInclusive.html):

```
#![feature(inclusive_range_syntax)]
for i in 0...255 {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are comparing different types so need to cast. Try this:

```
for num in 0..256 {
    let y = num as u8;
    if y == a {
        println!("found");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That is not exactly the issue here. The fact that the range `0..256` was inferred to have elements of the same type as `a` was what brought the compilation warning in the first place.

Comment: @E_net4 Actually, it works (I tested at least my casting version). Apparently an `as`-cast is not a valid hint for the compiler to infer the type. So in this example, it's probably a `Range<i32>`.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt I didn't say that this solution doesn't work. The problem is in the exposed reason, which is... well, prone to ambiguities.

Comment: so using `as` is not appropriate in this case? Lucas you say it is not a valid hint for compiler can you explain why?

Comment: @alex What actually happens is that `num as u8` tells the compiler that a cast from the range's element type to `u8` is needed, and "cuts" the type inference that would have occurred without it. Instead of assuming that `num` has the same type of `a`, and so inferring the range to a `Range<u8>`, it just "falls back" to `Range<i32>`.