# Idiomatic Rust way to overcome overflow in upper-exclusive Range

Tags: rust, idioms

Consider this example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut t: [u8; 256] = [0; 256];
    for i in 0..256u8 {
        t[i as usize] = i;
    }
    println!("{}", t[0]);
    println!("{}", t[1]);
    println!("{}", t[128]);
    println!("{}", t[254]);
    println!("{}", t[255]);
}
```

([code sample on play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=45ebc8a599aa5970c3a3e882da29aef4&version=stable&backtrace=0))

I want to initialize my array containing 256 values of unsigned integer of 8 bits. The initial value is defined by 0 for the first item and incremented for every successive element.

This code does not work.

The upper bound of the [`Range`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.Range.html) is exclusive, so the for loop's first value is 0, the last value is 255. My array has a length of 256 with indices ranging from first index 0 to last index 255. Sounds fine, but the upper limit is defined as "256u8" (a [`u8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u8.html)), a value which is technically 0 (`256 % 256 == 0`). Therefore the compiler warns me:

```
warning: literal out of range for u8
 --> <anon>:3:17
  |
3 |     for i in 0..256u8 {
  |                 ^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(overflowing_literals)] on by default
```

What is the most *Rust-idiomatic* way to overcome this warning?

**Disclaimer:** This is not a problem. It is just a warning and can easily solved with casts or a single assignment after the loop. I am asking about an *idiom*.

Comment: Thank you @Shepmaster, this is a duplicate. Sorry for improper search for duplicates. It seems that iterating over a larger type and casting is the idiomatic way to go. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40421720/1624929

Comment: No worries. Inclusive ranges are [getting closer and closer, though](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/28237)!